# Kafka error "Not authorized to access group:"

Tags: apache-kafka

Someone from my team has changed some configuration in Kafka and I don't know what was changed. No one admits to the changes. I have to explain this case.
From this time our applications show errors similar to this despite access to topics set to All:

```
2022-01-03 09:16:35,398] ERROR [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=test-connect] Uncaught exception in herder work thread, exiting:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:290)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access group: test-connect
```

Previously, access was set at the topic's and user's level, not at the group level and it worked well.

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: are you sure you're connected with the correct user?

Comment: yes, I've checked it.